# Load my Inline js footer area

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization

In WordPress we are used a editor that's name muffin builder. It's create dynamic google map script. I just put my Google Api key in this editor and apply it in my home page and its autonomic create a script. when we moved all js files in my footer section all js moved but map js not moved. we want to moved this inline js footer area. please help me to resolved this problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can enqueue your script in footer

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('handle', 'src', 'deps', 'ver', 'in_footer'); ?>
```

like `wp_enqueue_script('jquery','PATH_SCRIPT','','',true);`

Setting `$in_footer` to `true`

I see references here, please have look 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/